# fread is blocking if there is no data to read

Tags: php, sockets, fread, fsockopen

here's my problem :

I'm trying to send some specific query data to a server and some servers( game servers ) don't respond to the query protocol and the script is just giving me a timeout on the **fread($socket, 1024)** function.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\xampp\htdocs\file.php on line 85

Are you guys having an idea on how to just return false if there is no data to read ?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `socket_select` with a reasonable timeout (less than 10 sec), passing an array of single socket as a first argument. If `socket_select` returns 0, return false, else you can `fread` (at least once) without blocking. (Not posting as an answer 'cause I'm not really into PHP, so it could be wrong in many ways)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to use non-blocking sockets.

In PHP you can use the [`socket_set_nonblock`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-nonblock.php) function.